# E2E parallel tests failing with 2 or more windows open

Tags: testing, parallel-processing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have an angular-typescript program at work where I use testcafe for parallel e2e tests lately. The problem is, when I configure `-c 3` for concurrency tests, the tests always fail at project creation.
To not get too much into details. I basically let it test: Create Project -> Some other tests running under that specific project and move to the next project creation.

I usually get these two errors `403 Tokenization failed` and the for the tests running under the project I get `401 unauthorized`. I tried to fix the 403 with a mutex like this pseudo code below

```
if(token exists) 
  continue
else
  create new token
```

But it did not fix the parallel test problem. Do you guys have any idea or hint for me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the issue without an example project that shows it. Please share your detailed example in the testcafe repository using the following template: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml. You can use the following instruction to create a minimal working example: https://testcafe.io/402636/faq#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue

Comment: Hi, sry for the late answer. I can't share any code or code structure with you. This is against my company's policy. But what I can say is that I am basically doing API calls. And these APIs are used in all tests. Somehow it clashs while running tests in parallel because the bearer token is called twice in the test. I hope this information can help a little bit.

Comment: You do not need to use your company code to create an example. Create a project with minimal functionality that allows you to reproduce the bug.